# @import not working in addon with ember-cli-sass

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember.js-3

Addon has

```
// app/styles/my-addon.scss within addon
@import 'pods';
.testing123 .my-addon {
  color: white
}

// app/styles/pods.scss within addon
// @import 'some components go here';
.testing123 .pods {
  color: black
}
```

This works in the addon's dummy app. However when I build it into a real app:

```
// app/styles/app.scss
@import 'my-addon';
```

Now my app css contains

```
.testing123 .my-addon {
  color: white
}
// expect to see .texting123 .pods _but don't_
```

ember-cli-sass ^7.2.0 and ember-cli-sass-pods ^1.3.0 are both in addon's dependencies.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 29th August 2018**

Removed **ember-cli-sass-pods** and replaced with **ember-component-css**. Moved all sass into from **app/...** to **addon/...** and now everything is working (but of course I lose the ability to change sass variables in the app). But at least I can release.

Comment: what version of ember are you using?

Comment: Is the sass addon a `devDependency` in package.json? Try making it a `dependency` instead.

Comment: Did you do all the  addon specific steps in the README? Is the import at the very top of your file? (No comments above it) https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Ember 3.1.4

Comment: @handlebears yes it is a dependency (last line of question)

Comment: @handlebears pods import is at the top of the file

Comment: @bryan.crotaz can you confirm your addon is configured this way: https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass/blob/master/README.md#usage-within-in-repo-addon-and-in-repo-engine (at the bottom?)

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I'm not using Ember Engines - so not sure what you're saying I should have done?

Comment: I guess -- could you provide more specifics about your setup? like, what addon your using? if it's a custom addon, does it expose sass assets like in the above link (in the "in-repo addon" section)

Comment: addons I'm using:
ember-cli-typescript (hopefully irrelevant)
ember-cli-sass
ember-cli-sass-pods

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I've made clear in the question that the app is trying to import a sass asset from the addon and this isn't working

Comment: do you have control of the addon? can you change the import pods to import ./pods?

I'm still unsure if you control the addon or not and can make these kinds of changes :)


But yeah, ember-cli-typescript should be irrelevant for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have your styles defined in the `addon` folder and not the `app` folder.

Move your `styles` folder inside the `addon` folder into the `app` folder and try again.

Your styles will still be available in the addon and in the test dummy app but will not also be exported out to any app using your addon.

Comment: Agreed, this can cause stylesheet problems

Comment: styles in the addon folder were correctly folded into the vendor.css